# storing [Int:String] dictionaries to user.defaults crashes with SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

saving a bunch of data using user.default. everything saves fine except one dictionary [Int:String]. The funny part is this, I can save a dictionary [String:Int] fine, but as soon as its [Int:String], it crashes when I run my save function that has my code in it.

the console shows the follow:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object {
    99 = Jennifer;
} for key playernames'

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object that you are trying to save in the UserDefualt must be of type NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. As per apple docs:

> A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections, a combination of instances of) NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.
>   [UserDefault Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

The key of NSDictionary is a string or a type conforming to NSCopying protocol.
[image]

You can try this:

```
let yourData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourDictionary)
let userDefualts = UserDefaults.standard
userDefualts.set(yourData, forKey: "yourKey")
```

Comment: appreciate it, thank you very much. worked flawlessly. For those seeing this after, to unarchive what you have achieved, used the following swift 4: NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: Data)